# Have values of keys of dictionary mapped to their own key

Tags: dictionary, recursion, data-structures, hashmap, queue

I have this python dictionary

`dct = {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['D'], 'D': ['E'], 'C': ['F'], 'E': ['G']}`

and i need a function to return it as

`(A(B(D(E(G)))))(C(F))`

I am unable to map the elements of each values to their own values. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What type of data structure is the result? (`(A(B(D(E(G)))))(C(F))`)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at Python. I developed the function you want in Java. Hope you can convert it easily to Python.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapTheMap {
    // Count of open parentheses
    static int parentheses = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creating the map (i.e. dictionary in python)
        Map<Character, Character[]> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put('A', new Character[]{'B', 'C'});
        map.put('B', new Character[]{'D'});
        map.put('D', new Character[]{'E'});
        map.put('C', new Character[]{'F'});
        map.put('E', new Character[]{'G'});

        // The start key is A, you can develop a logic to get the first key if you want to
        Character key = 'A';
        System.out.print("(" + key);

        recursion(map, key);
    }

    public static void recursion(Map<Character, Character[]> map, Character key) {
        // If the map contains the key, add 1 parenthesis, print the value of that key, and call the function again with value as a key (Call 1: Key A -> Value B -- Call 2: Key B --> ...)
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            for (Character valueKey : map.get(key)) {
                parentheses++;
                System.out.print("(" + valueKey);
                recursion(map, valueKey);
            }
        }
        // If the map doesn't contain the key, print close parentheses 
        else {
            while (parentheses >= 0) {
                System.out.print(")");
                parentheses--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there is something you don't understand, tell me and I'll try to edit the answer.

Comment: Hey mate, thank you. I know it has been a year since you helped me out. And i want to say thank you

Answer (score 0):

The function map_nodes recursively traverses the whole dictionary and each key is a node. Every time a node is encountered in the dictionary, it is appended to the list that holds the desired structure and uses the children as new nodes one after the other.
Finally, the result is formatted accordingly as node and children.

```
def map_nodes(nodes):
   def build_structure(node):
      if node not in dct:
         return node
      children = ''.join([build_structure(child) for child in dct[node]])
         return f"({node}{children})"
                
   starting_node = next(iter(dct))
   return build_structure(starting_node)
            
dct = {'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['D'], 'D': ['E'], 'C': ['F'], 'E': ['G']} 
result = map_nodes(dct) print(result)
```